Help finding a morphism between injective resolutions
I'd like to prove the following result of homological algebra:
In an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$, given two objects $A$ and $B$, a morphism $\varphi \colon A \rightarrow B$ and two resolutions $I^{\bullet}$, $i \colon A \rightarrow I^0$ and $J^{\bullet}$, $j \colon B \rightarrow J^0$, if the second resolution is injective then there is a morphism of complexes $\phi^{\bullet} \colon I^{\bullet} \rightarrow J^{\bullet}$ such that $\phi^0 \circ i = j \circ \varphi$.
For reference, I'm following Voisin "Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry".
Finding $\phi^0$ is quite easy, you use the fact that $J^0$ is injective and $i$ is an injective morphism to extend $j \circ \varphi$ to a morphism from $I^0$ to $J^0$.
Now for $\phi^1$, we can't do the same since $d^0_I$ (the differential of the complex $I^{\bullet}$) is in general not injective. We consider $\pi \colon I^0 \rightarrow C$ defined as the cokernel of $i$. We want to find maps $C \rightarrow J^1$ and $C \rightarrow I^1$, with the second one injective, and then extend just like before. For the first map, we simply observe that $d^0_J \circ j \circ \varphi = 0$, hence by the universal property of the cokernel we know there is a map $\psi \colon C \rightarrow J^1$ with $\psi \circ \pi = d_J^0 \circ \phi^0$. Finally, we observe that $d_I^0 \circ i = 0$ since the complex $I^{\bullet}$ is exact, hence we get a map  $\xi \colon C \rightarrow I^1$. This is what I've managed to do. But I can't see why the second map I found should be injective. Could someone enlighten me?

As in many cases involving abelian categories, a diagram-chasing argument can be generalized to an arbitrary abelian category by replacing elements with "generalized elements", which are morphisms from some test object $U$ to the object in question.
In this case, to show the map $C \to I^1$ is a monomorphism, it suffices to show its kernel is 0; this is equivalent to showing that for any object $U$ and any morphism $c \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, C)$, if the composition with $C \to I^1$ is 0, then $c = 0$.  Now, since the quotient map $I^0 \to C$ is an epimorphism, we can find an epimorphism $\pi : V \to U$ and a generalized element $i^0 : V \to I^0$ making a commutative square with $c$.  (In particular, since epimorphisms are stable under pullbacks in an abelian category, it suffices to take $V$ to be the fibered product $U \times_C I^0$ and $\pi : V \to U$ the canonical projection morphism.)
From here, most of the rest proceeds as in the usual diagram-chasing argument in the case of $R$-modules: since $d\circ i^0 = 0$ and $0\to A \to I^0 \overset{d}\to I^1$ is exact, we can conclude that $i^0$ factors through $A$.  Therefore, from $C$ being the cokernel of the map $A \to I^0$, we can conclude that $c \circ \pi = 0$.  Since $\pi$ is an epimorphism, that implies $c = 0$, which was what we wanted to show.
(In general, to come up with an outline of the argument that will be required for a general abelian category, it can be useful to work out a proof for the case of $\mathsf{Ab}(X)$ for a topological space $X$ -- if you're familiar with that example.  Then, every time you use the fact that the image of $\varphi : \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G}$ is the subsheaf of $g \in \mathscr{G}(U)$ such that there exists an open cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U$ and sections $f_i \in \mathscr{F}(V_i)$ with $\varphi(V_i)(f_i) = g |_{V_i}$ -- replace that with an "epimorphic cover" $\pi : V\to U$ of the test object $U$ and a "lifting generalized element" $f : V \to \mathscr{F}$.  And every time you use the separatedness axiom of a sheaf, replace that with an application of the definition of epimorphism.  A use of the gluing axiom of a sheaf would translate into applying the fact that an abelian category is regular, so any epimorphism $\pi : V \to U$ is the coequalizer of the kernel pair $p_1, p_2 : V \times_U V \to V$.)

We surely don't need a diagram chase here; universal properties suffice

Sure, but I tend to find translating a diagram chase to be the easiest way to come up with proofs for general abelian categories - though admittedly not the most efficient proofs possible in many situations.

Thank you a lot for the answer. When you say that epimorphisms are stable under pullback, you mean that if $(P, p_1, p_2)$ is the pullback of $f \colon A \rightarrow C$ and $g \colon B \rightarrow C$ with $f \circ p_1 = g \circ p_2$ and if, say, $f$ is epi, then so is $p_1$?

sorry, just realized it's $p_2$, not $p_1$.

Yes, that's what it means to say epimorphisms are stable under pullback in some category with fibered products.

So when you say you can take $V$ and two morphisms, $i_0$ and $\pi$ with the latter epi, are you using the fact that in an abelian category pullback always exists?

Yes, it's using the fact that in an abelian category, pullbacks always exist, and epimorphisms are stable under those pullbacks.

Fix $A,B$ and monics $i:A\hookrightarrow I^\bullet$, $j:B\hookrightarrow J^\bullet$ which are resolutions. Assume $J^\bullet$ is a complex of injectives.
$j\phi$ lifts against $i$ as some $\phi_0$, you're right. Since $j_0\phi_0i$ vanishes, $j_0\phi$ factors through the cokernel of $i$, $I_0\twoheadrightarrow I_0/i(A)$; now, $i_0$ factors as $I_0\twoheadrightarrow I_0/i(A)\hookrightarrow I_1$ (here I use the resolution property to say that last map (i) exists and (ii) is a monic) and $I_0/i(A)\to J_1$ lifts against the monic $I_0/i(A)\hookrightarrow I_1$ and we have our $\phi_1:I_1\to J_1$, which satisfies $\phi_1i_0=j_0\phi_0$.
Re-reading your post, it seems you're unsure of injectivity of $I_0/i(A)\hookrightarrow I_1$. Well, $i_0$ factors as $I_0\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{Im}(i_0)\hookrightarrow I_1$; Abelian categories have epi-mono factorisation. Now, the epimorphism there (strictly speaking it is the coimage map) is $\mathrm{coker}\ker i_0$ and by exactness of $0\to A\to I_0\to I_1\to\cdots$ I know $\ker i_0$ is $i:A\hookrightarrow I_0$, so indeed $I_0\twoheadrightarrow I_0/i(A)$ is the (co)image of $i_0$.
Now we rinse and repeat. I'll do one more just to really convince you this works.
$j_1\phi_1$ vanishes on $i_0$, so it factors through $I_1\twoheadrightarrow I_1/i_0(I_0)$. Again, $I_1/i_0(I_0)\hookrightarrow I_2$ is monic (and is the kernel arrow of $i_2$) so our map $I_1/i_0(I_0)\to J_2$ coming from $j_1\phi_1$ lifts along that monic to give some $\phi_2:I_2\to J_2$, and because $i_1$ is $I_1\twoheadrightarrow I_1/i_0(I_0)\hookrightarrow I_2$ we have $\phi_2 i_1=j_1\phi_1$.
We go on... $\phi$ extends to a chain map $I^\bullet\to J^\bullet$. Moreover, it is possible to prove that $\phi$ is unique up to chain homotopy which is also very important! Maybe I leave that as an exercise...
